# Google apps script to insert multiple rows based on the number of variable column groups (generated by a Google form)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates, google-forms, master-detail

I'm an artist and have implemented an art show application for our local art group using Google Forms.  The application allows for an artist to submit a variable number of painting entries (up to a maximum amount which varies from show to show). This presents a classic master (single instance of artist information such as name, phone, email, etc.) detail (multiple instances of painting information such as title, media, image, etc.) relationship.  It's a classic problem that a relational database solves.  However, the ease of creating a Google Form and ease in which folks can work with spreadsheet data makes a compelling case to solve this problem using sheets.  As each painting detail is entered into the form (using conditional questions up to max entries) Google adds those detail cells horizontally extending the row. To date, I've managed to address the problem with a hodge-podge of very specific macros and other brute force methods to get this data lined up in columns so that it is workable (i.e., sort, slice/dice). I was about to attempt a crude generic script to try and solve this general problem but as I look at similar questions I see solutions that are 10 times more compact and efficient than anything I could cook up.  This is by no means my specific problem but rather a general need by Google forms users who process master/detail information and end up with unmanageable data strung out in rows of endless variable lengths. If Google was smart they would build this master/detail feature in and gain a raft of new form users.  Anyway, here is a view of the simulated captured form data: and the desired result.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lxuc6uCIkLXyx5evuWIEHULTAOwFwmjT627igC0JbfQ/edit?usp=sharing

[Master - Details from Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lxuc6uCIkLXyx5evuWIEHULTAOwFwmjT627igC0JbfQ/edit?usp=sharing)

The data in columnar format can now be processed with ease.  My thinking was to make this generic so I could apply it to any number of form applications that ask for fixed and variable information.  To do that I was going to set up variables for the starting cell of the detail data (in this case D or 4) ) the maximum number of detail clusters (in this case it was 5) and the number of cells in each
detail cluster (in this case 3).  The master information (name info) gets repeated as rows are inserted for each cell cluster. Ideally, the last cell cluster on a row could be determined on the fly rather than specifying a max. The first cell in a detail cluster would be a required form field so it's absence would indicate the end of the detail clusters on a row.

I get weak in the knees when I think about using arrays and was leaning toward doing this with lots of copying and pasting by way of macros when I thought I might seek some help from those who do this with seeming ease.

Comment: I didn't even read your question because it's too long, it has no images for examples,you didn't post any code that you have already tried and I don't follow links to spreadsheets.

Comment: Didn't include workaround code/manual formulas that solve a very specific instance which is not applicable to the more general solution I'm seeking that could help other Google Form users with this common problem.  Typed in the data up top but when processed below for display lost all formatting - thus the link. I was hoping a Google Forms support person might pick off this question and take it as a broader suggestion to include a  master/detail sectional attribute in Google Forms. Of course, if I can can it solved here that helps me out directly.  Was thinking of a bigger picture too.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation: form with the start block, followed by repeated blocks of same questions. I successfully unwrapped it and pushed everything to BigQuery database by using Apps Script.

My guess is that you don't have tons of data, so you can keep everything in Google Sheets. You posted no code, but the strategy should be like this:

1. Use another sheet in the same spreadsheet for writing your data with the desired structure.
2. Keep the sheet that form writes into intact, you don't want to mess up GF->GS automation.
3. Use onFormSubmit event to process new rows that form writes into GS sheet.
4. Yes, you'll have to play with the arrays and use something like DetailsStartColumn(4) and DetailsWidth(3) to process horizontals blocks, detect filled/empty blocks and write them into your database on another sheet.

Arrays in Apps Script are fine, they are a great tool once you learn them, they are one of the reasons why I like JavaScript ;-)

Comment: Yep - Never touch the original.  Did contemplate onFormSubmit but was looking to do something after the fact to avoid the risk of distorting data en route to the original sheet.  Hadn't thought of intercepting and rerouting to a new sheet.  Thanks for the suggestion.